# Polymer JS – template repeat does nothing with my array. (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, polymer, repeat

This does nothing in my code..

```
<template repeat="{{item in list}}"> </template>
```

I have tried to also use as below but I get errors with this method:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="example" items="{{list}}"></template>
```

And i get the following errors with `is="dom-repeat"`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom.addDebouncer is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom is not a function
```

Why?

Here is my code

```
<link rel="import" href="../lib/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<link rel="import" href="../lib/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="welcome-title.html">

<dom-module id="remove-user">

<template>
  <iron-ajax id="getAll" url="http://localhost:3002/secure/api/all" method="GET" handle-as="json" on-response="getAllCB" with-credentials='true'></iron-ajax>

    <div class="ui relaxed stackable grid centered" id="admin-container">
        <welcome-title class="ui center aligned row grid"></welcome-title>
        <form class="ui grid remove-user hide twelve wide column" method='post' action="/secure/add-user">
            <h3>Remove User</h3>

            <table class="ui unstackable celled table ">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th class="nine wide">Username</th>
                        <th class="three wide">Permission</th>
                        <th class="one wide"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> ...
```

Here is where I am confused. I have simplified the loop to make it easier to debug but it doesn't appear. Although any text outside of the template repeat appears. There are no errors in the console.

```
                    <template repeat="{{user in users}}">
                        <span>{{user}}</span>
                    </template>
```

Why does nothing inside the repeat not show up on my page?

```
                    ... <tr>
                        <td><span></span></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="collapsing">
                            <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox"> <label></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                <tfoot class="full-width">

                    <tr><th colspan="3">

                        <button class="right floated negative ui button"><i class="remove user icon"></i>Remove User(s)</button>
                    </th>
                </tr></tfoot>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</template>



</dom-module>
<script>

Polymer({

    is: "remove-user",

    ready: function(){

        this.$.getAll.generateRequest();

    },

    getAllCB: function(data){

        this.users = data.detail.response;
    }

});

</script>
```

The users JSON object looks like this when outputting to browser console using JSON.stringify():

```
[{"username":"admin","permission":"admin"},            
{"username":"admin","permission":"application1"},
{"username":"user","permission":"application1"},
{"username":"test","permission":"application1"}]
```

Access to the complete project:
The file in question is under `authentication/public/elements/remove-user.html`
The main page that loads this elements is `authentication/secure.html`
https://github.com/CoultonF/Web-Development-3-Node.JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to use an expression inside a data binding, which Polymer 1.x does not support (nor is it on the roadmap for 2.x).

The correct form of this code:

```
<template repeat="{{user in users}}">
  <span>{{user}}</span>
</template>
```

is this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}" as="user">
  <span>{{user}}</span>
</template>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      users: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => ['Andy', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}" as="user">
        <span>{{user}}</span>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/aJOpWW?editors=1010)

You can read more about the `dom-repeat` template in the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat).

Comment: So I tried your solution, I was given the console errors: 
Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom.addDebouncer is not a function 

AND

Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom is not a function

Comment: What version of Polymer are you using?

Comment: 1.8.0 downloaded using bower

Comment: Can you show the full context of your code? The `dom-repeat` itself is correct, as can be seen in the codepen.

Comment: I added a github link to the entire project. The file in question is from authentication/secure.html and the polymer elements are under public/elements. If you are wanting to do testing, the username is admin and password is admin123#

Comment: Where are you using `dom-repeat`?

Comment: I found the problem. I was watching a tutorial and I had put in my secure.html folder  –  window.Polymer.dom = "shadow";   Once I commented this out it works, and the errors make sense now.

Comment: https://github.com/CoultonF/Web-Development-3-Node.JS/blob/master/authentication/secure.html   @Line 25 was the error.